# Der Unterschied zwischen "räsonieren" und "streiten"

Tags: difference

> Wann immer deutsche Politiker oder Publizisten über die Krise in Griechenland **räsonieren**, kommen sie selten ohne zwei vermeintliche Wahrheiten aus.

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *räsonieren* und *streiten*? Ist *räsonieren* formeller als *streiten*?

Comment: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/raesonieren

Comment: Mit Aussagen, welche Wörter man kennen *muss* und welche nicht, würde ich mich zurückhalten. Und vor allem würde ich das Wort in einem NGram doch eher mit Synonymen (z.B. motzen, nörgeln) vergleichen: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=räsonieren%2Cmotzen%2C+nörgeln&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cräsonieren%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmotzen%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cnörgeln%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Nur so nebenbei: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=räsonieren%2Craisonnieren%2Craisonieren&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cräsonieren%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Craisonnieren%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Craisonieren%3B%2Cc0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vorneweg zwei Anmerkungen:

1. Räsonieren kommt aus dem französischen *raisonner* („argumentieren“)
2. Ich komme aus Baden, einem Gebiet mit starkem französischem Einfluss, das heißt, das Folgende ist nicht unbedingt allgemeingültig.

Zum Streiten braucht es mindestens zwei Beteiligte, die sich zu einem Thema emotional unterhalten. Es kann von einer lebhaften Diskussion bis zu einem handfesten Streit alles sein.

Streiten ist an sich wertneutral, es ist aber auch keine neutrale Diskussion. Siehe dazu auch [Huberts Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/20386/974).

Räsonieren kann man auch alleine, aber auch in einer Diskussion. Wer räsoniert, wertet Argumente ab und versucht anhand dieser Argumente zu einem Ergebnis zu kommen. Wenn man alleine räsoniert, dann ist das der Versuch einer Meinungsbildung. Wer in einer Diskussion räsoniert, zeigt, dass er (noch) keine fertige Meinung hat, und es kann gut sein, dass es sehr konfus wirkt.

Räsonieren ist im Gegensatz zum Argumentieren ungeordnet. Ein Ergebnis des Räsonierens ist eine gebildete Meinung und eine Argumentation (oder auch das Eingeständnis, dass man keinen Schritt weiterkommt und sich nicht entscheiden kann).

[Wiktionary](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/r%C3%A4sonieren) definiert räsonieren als:

> Bedeutungen:
>
> (1) umgangssprachlich, über etwas räsonieren: über etwas schimpfen, sich
>   (lautstark) über etwas beschweren
>
> (2) etwas mit vielen Worten aussprechen
>
> (3) vernünftig über etwas nachdenken

[Huberts Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/20386/974) stellt eher (1) in den Vordergrund, ich kenne es stärker als (3) und (2). Wie bereits erwähnt bin ich in der Nähe zu Frankreich aufgewachsen, d. h., da zeigt sich evtl. eine stärkere Nähe zur Bedeutung des französischen Originals.

Answer (score 1):

Räsonieren im Sinn von Streiten? Echt? Wo hast du das gehört? Das kann ich mir kaum vorstellen, denn die beiden Wörter haben gänzlich unterschiedliche Bedeutungen.

### Streiten

Zum Streiten braucht man (mindestens) zwei. Streiten ist ein emotional geführter Dialog, den zwei Parteien mit gegensätzlichen Meinungen führen. Da ein Streit, anders als eine Diskussion, eine sehr starke emotionale Komponente hat, kann ein Streit sehr laut werden und manchmal zu Handgreiflichkeiten übergehen.

**Merkmale des Streitens sind:**

- Die beiden (selten auch mehr) Streithähne reden *mit*einander, nicht *über*einander.
- Man versucht nicht, Dritte von den negativen Seiten des Gesprächspartners zu überzeugen, sondern wirft ihm die Vorwürfe direkt ins Gesicht.
- Zum Streiten braucht man kein Publikum, sondern jemanden, der bereit ist eine gegensätzliche Meinung emotional zu vertreten.
- Ein Streit kann zu Handgreiflichkeiten führen.

### Räsonieren

Räsonieren kann man ganz alleine, denn das ist eine Form eines Monologs. Synonyme für *räsonieren* sind: nörgeln, schimpfen, motzen, meckern usw. Wenn jemand in einer Rede, oder bei einem Interview sehr wortreich über jemand anderen herzieht, kann man das räsonieren nennen. Aber bei einer Rede spricht derjenige ganz allein, und in einem Interview zieht der vor dem Mikrofon nicht über den her, der das Mikro hält, sondern über jemanden, der abwesend ist.

**Merkmale des Räsonierens sind:**

- Man spricht nicht *mit,* sondern *über* jemanden.
- Man stellt denjenigen, dem die Rede gilt, als schlecht dar.
- Das Räsonieren ist ein längerer Vorgang, bei dem mit vielen emotionalen Worten immer wieder dieselbe Botschaft transportiert wird.
- Beim Räsonieren braucht man ein Publikum, das man damit von den schlechten Eigenschaften des (meist abwesenden) Gegenstands der Rede überzeugen will.

### Stilistischer Unterschied

**Streiten** ist ein Wort, das nicht wertet. Wenn zwei miteinander streiten, kann das gute Gründe haben; es ist aber auch denkbar, dass sie sich über etwas in die Haare kriegen, das Außenstehenden völlig belanglos erscheint.

Bei **Räsonieren** klingt aber mit, dass die Person, die den Monolog führt, einerseits eine etwas affektierte und überhebliche Ausdrucksweise verwendet, oder dass der Redner mit seiner Meinung nur eine begrenzte Anhängerschaft findet, weil seine Meinung nicht der allgemeinen Meinung entspricht.

Comment: Ich find das räsonieren hier zu negativ dargestellt. Für mich hat räsonieren auch die Bedeutung vom laut denken - man macht einen Monolog über ein Thema ohne bereits zu einem Schluss gekommen zu sein. Wer räsoniert redet ins unreine und bildet sich erst noch seine Meinung.